# The player sticks on the screen for half a second while pressing 2 keys at the same time

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

For the moment, I'm making a 2d rpg game in java.
I just finished the KeyAdapter class and added it to my canvas:

```
public class KeyManager extends KeyAdapter {

    private float speed = 3;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            Level.getLevel();
            Levels.setVelY(+speed);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            Level.getLevel();
            Levels.setVelY(-speed);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            Level.getLevel();
            Levels.setVelX(+speed);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            Level.getLevel();
            Levels.setVelX(-speed);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            speed = 5;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        Level.getLevel();
        Levels.setVelX(0);
        Level.getLevel();
        Levels.setVelY(0);
        speed = 3;
    }

}
```

In fact everything works okay, but if I press two keys at the same time(for example the up and right Arrowkey), my player stops moving (I think the good translation is sticks)for about half a second. Can someone explain me why that is and how I can solve the problem. It's pretty annoying.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be a delay between the time that the speed is reset (I'm assuming velocity is decreased somewhere), and the time the key handler kicks in? (whoops, Nvm, it gets reset on a key release).

Comment: And what does a prefix of `+` do? Afaik, that does nothing unlike a unary negation.

Comment: And what does getLevel do?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the velocity being reset on the key release?

Comment: If i comment it out, it just keeps moving; I can't stop. That is not realy what I want

Comment: By the way, the Level.getLevel(); method is just the way eclipse wants me to access the velocity from the current level because I made it(the velocity)static.

Comment: Ya, I know you'll keep moving in the long run; it was a test, not a solution. I mean is there still a delay if you switch keys? And are you sure the delay happens when you press another key, and not when you release a previous one?

Comment: Yes, there is. But now the player doesn't stop but he stays walking the the direction from the first key instead of going directly to the correct direction(for half a second). The only difference is: it only happens if I press 2 opposite keys(e.g. up <-> down, right <->left...)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure.